# Converting GMT time to Epoch

Tags: c, datetime

I'm having much trouble converting a GMT time to a unix EPOCH time.

The problem seems to relate to mktime.  My current timezone is +13 hrs ahead.
I think this is the issue, mktime assumes localtime and when it calculates an epoch is returning a value that is about 12hrs before what the real GMT time is.

Here is my code.

```
time_t t;
struct tm tm;
strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", &tm);
tm.tm_isdst = -1; // -1 tells mktime figure it out
t = mktime(&tm);
```

When s = "2018-01-19T03:35:12Z", it's computing the epoch to be 1516286112
Instead of an epoch which should be about 12hrs ahead.

On a system where the BIOS clock is set to GMT, this error does not occur.
So I can only conclude that mktime is working as expected when that situation is true.

Incidentally, the string is coming from a nosql server which is displaying the correct time on a document.  I'm grabbing the current epoch and comparing it to the parsed date from the document and computing the difference.  This is where it all goes haywire!

Comment: mktime takes in local time...

Comment: Yep, that's the problem then.  I guess I can compute it and add offset seconds.

Comment: I wrote [some code](https://github.com/paulgriffiths/pgtime/blob/master/pgtime.c) to do this, once. It's not particularly pretty, but usually works. `timegm()` is not standard, but may be available to you.

Comment: Change timezone and then call `mktime()`.

Comment: Note: `struct tm tm;
strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", &tm); tm.tm_isdst = -1;` is technically insufficient as other members in `tm` may exist uninitialized.  Better to first `struct tm tm = {0};`

Comment: Thanks @chux! That actually fixes it!  Please put that as an answer.  I only want to compute dates based on UTC.  Never realized the impact of not doing so.

Comment: This was also helpful in describing my issue.  With another solution.  https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2013/06/11/time/

Comment: @Matt I do not have the time, now.  You can post your own answer.

Comment: Btw, the word [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) means the reference date, which in Unix is **1970-01-01 00:00Z**. You can't compute a "different epoch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is `mktime` is respecting the local timezone.

To fix that use **`timegm`** where available.  Or roll your own from this answer.

[Minimal implementation of gmtime algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745255/minimal-implementation-of-gmtime-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

> Converting GMT time to Epoch

`mktime()` does the heavy work of Y-M-D.h:m:s to linear time conversion, yet it assumes a local time.

For fun, below is a portable solution that does not change the timezone, nor assumes `time_t` is itself "seconds since Jan 1, 1970".

It calculates the 2 `time_t` for the GMT time-stamp and Jan 2, 1970 as if they where local times.  Their difference found with `difftime()` is in seconds (Unix time like), regardless of the units used with `time_t`.  The quotient of difference/seconds-per-day, rounded to the nearest whole number (to address DST and timezone adjustments < 12 hours) is the day offset since the Unix epoch.  The local time-ness of `mktime()` is effectively canceled in the difference and rounding.   Jan 2, instead of Jan 1, is used to avoid Local Jan 1, 1970 may be before GMT Jan 1,1970.  Some `mktime()` report -1 in those cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

static time_t ymd_to_time_t(int year1900, int monthJan, int day) {
  struct tm tm = {0};
  tm.tm_year = year1900;
  tm.tm_mon = monthJan;
  tm.tm_mday = day;
  return mktime(&tm);
}

#define SECS_PER_DAY (24.0*60*60)

// Only 6 members of gmt are relevant
long long GMT_time_to_Unix_Epoch(const struct tm *gmt) {
  time_t t0 = ymd_to_time_t(1970-1900, 1-1, 2);
  if (t0 == (time_t)-1) return t0;
  time_t t1 = ymd_to_time_t(gmt->tm_year, gmt->tm_mon, gmt->tm_mday);
  if (t1 == (time_t)-1) return t1;
  double d = difftime(t1, t0);
  long days = lrint(d/SECS_PER_DAY) + 1;  // + 1 for (Jan 2 - Jan 1)
  long long Unix_Epoch = ((days*24LL + gmt->tm_hour)*60 + gmt->tm_min)*60 + gmt->tm_sec;
  return Unix_Epoch;
}

int main(void) {
  struct tm tm = {0};
  tm.tm_year = 2018 - 1900;
  tm.tm_mon = 1 -1 ;
  tm.tm_mday = 19;
  tm.tm_hour = 3;
  tm.tm_min = 35;
  tm.tm_sec = 12;
  printf("%lld\n", GMT_time_to_Unix_Epoch(&tm));
}
```

Output

```
1516332912
```

---

Pedantically, if a timezone shifted which side of the international date line it was on since 1970, this approach is off.  E.g [kiribati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B14:00)

Comment: Thanks chux.  Good thing I don't have to worry about kiribati.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `tm_gmtoff`, use code as following :

```
int64_t time = mktime(&tm_time);
time += tm_time.tm_gmtoff;
if (tm_time.tm_isdst == 1){
    time -= 3600;
}
```